# OnSemi NCV1076 Ltspice Model Lib

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, ltspice, simulation

I am trying to desing a SMPS with LTSpice. There is a driver which ı can use in real.
It is NCV1076.
But ı could not find a .Lib Model to use in LTSpice.
There is a simulation model but it is only for SIMPLIS and it says encrypted model.
Is there any way to use them in Ltspice or is there any other model type in OnSemi WebSite.

Comment: No, you cannot use encrypted models from other simulators (SIMPLIS) in LTspice. You may consider looking/asking in the [LTspice group](https://groups.io/g/LTspice) to see if anyone there can help you. There are some fantastic people there. So please consider joining and asking there., But a quick search there tells me that they haven't already developed such a model for you. But they can help you., I think. Try them out.

Comment: What type of characteristics do you want to highlight with this switcher? I mean ac for stability or switching? I made the SIMPLIS model many years ago. I remember discussing with the designer about the feedback block in this part.

Comment: I am new with SMPS designes. Before the draw PCB. I want to simulate all details with this switch